# Remove one child node from a parrent node with more than 1 node of the same name

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file t hat I'm gonna delete 1 node from...
And here is it:

```
<games>
  <game>
    <gameName>Test6</gameName>
    <exePath>E:\LeagueOfLegends\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe</exePath>
    <Files>
      <file>C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\334.jpg</file>
      <file>C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\341.jpg</file>
      <file>C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\compressed\334.jpg</file>
      <file>C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\compressed\341.jpg</file>
      <file>C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\compressed\Test1\334.jpg</file>
      <file>C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\compressed\Test1\341.jpg</file>
    </Files>
 </game>
</games>
```

And my problem is... I want to delete one of the file nodes... That contains "C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\334.jpg"  as inner text...

And my code for that is at the moment(And it's not working):

```
private void removeFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).ToString();
        String gpsPath = appDataFolder + "/GameProfileSaver";
        String gName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(gpsPath + "/games.xml");

        foreach (string li in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            string liS = li.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
            XmlNode file = doc.SelectSingleNode("games/game[gameName='" + gName + "']/Files[@file='" + liS + "']");
            file.ParentNode.RemoveChild(file);               
        }
        doc.Save(gpsPath + "/games.xml");
}
```

And I'm just getting a NullReferenceException.... And when I tried something else.. That I don't have the code for now.. Is that it deleted the whole  node...

Comment: Haven't done XPath in ages, but I'm pretty sure `@` is used for attributes (`@file=`).  In any case, `file.ParentNode.RemoveChild(file)` doesn't look right - it's almost like you're telling it to delete itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Linq2Xml?

```
string nodeToDelete = @"C:\Users\Stian\Desktop\toComp\334.jpg";
var xDoc =  XDocument.Load(fname);

xDoc.Descendants()
    .First(n => (string)n == nodeToDelete)
    .Remove();

string newXml = xDoc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNode file = doc.SelectSingleNode("games/game[gameName='" + gName + "']/Files/file['" + liS + "']");
```

works for me